# fetch a number value - create image through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, fetch

I do a fetch with JS, for example:
According to the API dev, i dont need any PHP myself.  Any info on how to make this work, or information sources, would be appreciated.
(if someone knows a better title, let me know)

71562 shows this image:
[emblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwan7.png)

33994 shows this image:
[emblem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQYHF.png)

so they are combinations of a pattern, color and emblem overlay.

```
function test () {
    fetch("https://api.examplesite.com/example/Spoons")
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then ((out) => {
            console.log(out.emblem) // out.emblem returns the numeric value
        })
}
```

the console.log outputs:

```
{name: 'Spoons', realmID: 1, realm: 'Albion', emblem: 71562, realmPoints: 123888, …}
bountyPoints: 5
emblem: 71562 //this is the value needed to somehow create the emblem
members: 17
name: "Spoons"
realm: "Albion"
realmID: 1
realmPoints: 123888
```

the emblem number should represent a picture that you can form, with javascript (sprites, overlaying images) but no idea how.

this information i have is this:

> emblems are made overlaying template colors etc
> the string text i output in /guild should be enough to build id
> given the correct icon files, bear with me

this is the PHP behind it, that i received from the API developer:

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: image/png');
$emblem = $_GET['emblem'];
$thumbnail = $_GET['thumbnail'];

$hex = dechex($emblem);
$bin = hexbin($hex);
if ($emblem > 65500)
$logo = substr($bin,-18,-9);
else 
$logo = substr($bin,-16,-9);
$logobin = bindec($logo);
$pattern = substr($bin,-9,-7);
$patternbin = bindec($pattern);
$primary = substr($bin,-7,-3);
$primarybin = bindec($primary);
$secondary = substr($bin,-3,3);
$secondarybin = bindec($secondary);
if($patternbin==3)
{
    $secondarybin = 0;
}
$background = imagecreatefrompng("../images/guildshields/$primarybin-$secondarybin-$patternbin-full.png"); 
$img = imagecreatefromgif("../images/guildshields/Emblems/$logobin.gif");
if ($emblem > 65000)
{
$img2 = imagecreatetruecolor(64, 64);
imagealphablending($img2, false);
imagesavealpha($img2, true);
imageCopyResampled($img2, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 64, 128, 128);
}
else 
$img2 = $img;
$img2_width = imagesx($img2);
$img2_height = imagesy($img2);
$bg_width = imagesx($background);
$bg_height = imagesx($background);
imagecopy($background, $img2, ($bg_width-$img2_width)/2, ($bg_height-$img2_height)/2, 0, 0, $img2_width, $img2_height);
if ($thumbnail == "true")
{
    $im = $background;
    $width=ImageSx($im); // Original picture width is stored
    $height=ImageSy($im); // Original picture height is stored
    $thumb=imagecreatetruecolor($width/2,$height/2);
    imageCopyResized($thumb,$im,0,0,0,0,$width/2,$height/2,$width,$height);
    imagepng($thumb);
}
else
{
    imagepng($background); 
}

function hexbin($hex)
{
   $bin='';
   for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i++)
       $bin.=str_pad(decbin(hexdec($hex[$i])),4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
       return $bin;
} 
?>
```

and last bit of information i got from the API dev is this:

this gets the string i output from the api

`$emblem = $_GET['emblem'];`

> and this is taking all the infos from that string, the logo will be held in the 9-16 position of the string

```
$bin = hexbin($hex);
if ($emblem > 65500)
$logo = substr($bin,-18,-9);
else 
$logo = substr($bin,-16,-9);
$logobin = bindec($logo);
$pattern = substr($bin,-9,-7);
$patternbin = bindec($pattern);
$primary = substr($bin,-7,-3);
$primarybin = bindec($primary);
$secondary = substr($bin,-3,3);
$secondarybin = bindec($secondary);
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how the get an image instead of just the number

Comment: ok then, you need to call the php page, as in `https://yoursite.com/script.php?emblem=71562&thumbnail=true`

Comment: you simply pass it querystring parameters, `emblem` (which is your number) and `thumbnail` (which is true or false, I don't know what it does)

Comment: thanks i can indeed grab the image now
I think the guy more expects me to rewrite it with JS to reform the image.  (he gave me a image folder)  but thats something for a new question maybe.  This one is answered, cheers.